# Select EndDown, and then a further 2 rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have the below code which selects all data below A5, includes the 17 columns on the right of it, and then offsets by one so I don't clear the title row.

```
Set wksdestination = Sheets("Continental")
Set registcell = wksdestination.Range("A5")
Set rngdata = Range(registcell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 17), registcell.Offset(1, 0))
rngdata.Clear
```

I also need it to clear the two rows **below** the end row as well as there are occasionally some SUM functions in the cells two below some of the columns. Can someone help with the last bit of adding the two rows below selection as well?

I tried

```
Set wksdestination = Sheets("Continental")
Set registcell = wksdestination.Range("A5")
Set rngdata = Range(registcell.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 17), registcell.Offset(1, 0))
rngdata.Clear
```

But that gives a **Run-time error '1004'**

I have also tried the below, but it breaks if there is no data, and isn't ideal as it involves selecting the different sheets, would prefer if it ran without selecting each sheet, but if that's the only way then that'll have to do

```
Set wksdestination = Sheets("Continental")
Set registcell = wksdestination.Range("A5")
Set rngdata = Range(registcell.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 17), registcell.Offset(1, 0))
wksdestination.Select
Range(rngdata.Offset(2, 0), rngdata).Select
Selection.Clear
```

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your second code sample as long as there is something below A5 to stop the `.End(xlDown)` from going all the way to the bottom of the worksheet. If it does go all the way to A1048576, it cannot `.Offset(2, 17)` because there are no more rows to go down.

Comment: It isn't working even when there is data :( Same error code
`Application-defined or object-defined error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternate method of cell range selection and offset that guards against there being no data below A5.

```
Dim wksdestination As Worksheet
Set wksdestination = Sheets("Continental")
With wksdestination
    With .Range("A5").Resize(Application.Max(2, .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 3), 17)
        .Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    End With
End With
```

At a minimum, the two rows below A5 will be cleared of content and formulas (but not formatting) from column A to column Q.

Comment: Thanks! That does the job! I changed the ClearContents to Clear as I want it to remove the formatting as well, and also the 17 meant it wasn't picking up the 18th column which the offset was so I changed that to 18. But perfect answer! Thanks :)